# Make R CMD INSTALL call autoconf before ./configure

Tags: r, configure, autoconf, r-package

when I install or check my own R-package using:

```
devtools::check()
```

I need to have a configure file in my package. However, it would be useful if R automatically calls autoconf **before** and **then** configure. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: put that into the top-level `configure` and have the other toolchain in another location/dir. but, not all systems are going to have `autoconf` available and it's unlikely this will get into CRAN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not really part of the R workflow into which devtools is hooking itself.

In fact, there is [open / mostly unanswered proposal](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.packages.devel/784) I sent as part of [this r-package-devel thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.packages.devel/782/focus=784). Re-generating `configure` is another possible use case.

But in the narrow sense, *you* are expected to call `autoconf` after you make changes to `configure.ac` and *before* you invoke `R CMD check` (and it doesn't matter whether or not you do this via devtools).